# Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

No seguinte código, ocorre o seguinte erro, que não consigo perceber o porquê:

> Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object na linha 21

```
<?php
require('config.php');


if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM registo WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result= $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
    {    
       $user = $result->fetch_object();//linha 21
        if(password_verify($password,$user->password))
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['user'] = true;
            header("Location: home.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Resumo:

Mude isto:

```
 $user = $result->fetch_object();
```

Para isto:

```
 $user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Isto terá o resultado em array, *não em objeto*.

Se realmente deseja utilizar o  `fetch_object()` você terá que usar o driver do [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php). Isto irá permitir usar o `get_result()`.

```
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
//...
$user = $resutado->fetch_object();
```

Neste caso:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{    
    $user = $result->fetch_object();//linha 21
    if(password_verify($password,$user->password))
    {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        header("Location: home.php");
```

---

Agora a explicação por trás do erro é simples.

Quando você usa:

```
$result = $stmt->store_result();
```

Segundo a [própria documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php), *não precisa acreditar em mim*, o `$result` se torna um valor booleano, `true` ou `false`.

Portanto fazer isto:

```
$result = $stmt->store_result();

$user = $result->fetch_object();
```

É equivalente a fazer:

```
$user = true->fetch_object();
```

Que logicamente não funcionará.

Quando executa o `$stmt->store_result()` é a variavel `$stmt` que armazenou o resultado e não a resposta do `store_result`.

Para que você consiga obter a resposta numa variavél fora do `$stmt` você precisará utilizar o `get_result()`. Supondo que use `$x = $stmt->get_result()`, 
o `get_result()` irá retornar o conteúdo, portanto o  `$x` terá todo o resultado da query.

Comment: $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object(), usei sua sugestao e aparece o mesmo erro.